# Parsing certificates with bouncycastle

Tags: java, security, certificate

I'm a certificate noob. I've been trying to import certificates for the past couple of hours and the more I dig into security stuff, the more it feels impossible to understand.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve in java:

- the user can upload any kind of formatted certificate with an optional passphrase
- I need to convert the certificate to a non-binary PEM format
- Extract the private and public keys to store in a database, throw error if missing one of the two

So far I've been able to parse some certificates using java security's x509Certificate but I can't get the private key. I've also tried bouncy castle but no success there either.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

An `X509Certificate` only contains a public key.

Private keys are usually encoded using PKCS#8. Try `KeyFactory` with a `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`.

Combined public key certificates with private keys are usually encoded using PKCS#12 (.pfx, .p12). Try a `KeyStore` of "PKCS12" type (with Bouncy Castle as provider).